# how to make a Questionnaire iPhone app with sqlite

Tags: iphone

I want to make an iPhone app just like a questionnaire/Quize, and want to store all questions in sqlite database , i need to have One question that can be a label and 4 radio buttons for answers, user will select the option and will go for the next question, questions and answers will be saved in sqlite and at the end user will come to know how many he made correct or wrong choices.

Please suggest me any tutorial or anything that can be help full for me,please guise i will be   grateful to u for this kindness in advance.

Comment: Ask with Amitaabh to give source code of KBC..

Answer (score 0):

Just make a database with a table with columns like so : id, question, answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4,correct answer, did answer correct;

If you don't know SQL just use a wrapper like [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)

After that just us use the built in function to get from database the question with a certain id (i.e. question number) and pass that to your question-asking class . When the user presses on an answer, check if it's correct and modify "did answer correct" columns.

Answer (score 0):

Break your project into set of questions:
1. How to create GUI in iPhone?
2. How to connect to database in iPhone?
3. How to create label, radio buttons in iPhone?
4. How to submit form in iPhone?
Etc.

Then search the web for each of these. Perform these examples individually, test them and combine them.

Voila you've got a brand new questionnaire application :)!!!